# Uninitialized constant CustomTokenResponse(NameError) and Unauthorized Access for Valid Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, doorkeeper

I have been trying to migrate my rails app to api and i just installed doorkeeper gem for authentication and it generates me a token for a valid user. Now i have two problems

1. It shows unauthorized access in logs when i try to get page even though my access token is correct
2. I tried to put a custom token response for login and logout because it wasn't showing me any but it is now throwing me an error when i tried to run rails server

I have followed this guide for the process

https://scotch.io/@jiggs/rails-api-doorkeeper-devise

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

#Doorkeeper.rb

Doorkeeper.configure do
  # Change the ORM that doorkeeper will use (needs plugins)
  orm :active_record

  # This block will be called to check whether the resource owner is authenticated or not.
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    # raise "Please configure doorkeeper resource_owner_authenticator block located in #{__FILE__}"
    # Put your resource owner authentication logic here.
    # Example implementation:
    current_user || warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)
  end

   resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(:email => params[:email])
    if user && user.valid_for_authentication? { user.valid_password?(params[:password]) }
      user
    end
  end

  skip_authorization do
    true
  end

  Doorkeeper::OAuth::TokenResponse.send :prepend, CustomTokenResponse
  Doorkeeper::OAuth::ErrorResponse.send :prepend, CustomTokenErrorResponse

  # WWW-Authenticate Realm (default "Doorkeeper").
  #
  # realm "Doorkeeper"
end
```

```
# lib/custom_token_response.rb

module CustomTokenResponse
  def body
    user_details = User.find(@token.resource_owner_id)
    # call original `#body` method and merge its result with the additional data hash
       super.merge({
           status_code: 200,
           message: I18n.t('devise.sessions.signed_in'),
           result: user_details
       })
  end
end
```

```
# lib/custom_token_error_response.rb

module CustomTokenErrorResponse
  def body
    {
      status_code: 401,
      message: I18n.t('devise.failure.invalid', authentication_keys: User.authentication_keys.join('/')),
      result: []
    }
    # or merge with existing values by
    # super.merge({key: value})
  end
end
```

1: from /home/rubyians/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
/home/rubyians/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in`block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant CustomTokenResponse (NameError)

Comment: did you restart server ?

Comment: @Vishal My server is not starting it throws me this error :1: from /home/rubyians/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in without_bootsnap_cache'
/home/rubyians/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:inblock in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant CustomTokenResponse (NameError)

Comment: in the application.rb file did you write this `config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"`?

Comment: @Vishal Thanks ! That's seemed to work for my second issue. Now my first issue is remaining it shows unauthorized even if give correct access token.

Comment: Did you added token type `bearer` before token?

Comment: @Vishal yes i did

Comment: It should work. try to login again with oauth token. and use it . again. make sure you didn't use devise authentication method `authenticate_user!` instead of doorkeeper method `doorkeeper_authorize!`

Comment: @Vishal yeah i tried replacing it with doorkeeper authorize but it now throws me error undefined user_project which i defined with     
user_projects = current_user.user_projects.includes(:project)

Comment: Is this because it's not using the devise authentication?

Comment: In doorkeeper you can access current_user with `current_resource_owner`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had to do some more configuration you know Jayakrishnan aka JK ? He worked with you in moodit app he helped me.

Comment: Nope i am working in another project in the same company and he is my mentor.

Comment: Ya i will pass it to him.

Comment: Hey bro he asked you to contact him i will give you his contact number where shall i send it to you ?

Comment: Yea i will send it over there.